# Type to find user should maintain the sort order selected

Tags: bug, status-completed, users

Find as you type user feature always sorts on name. I find it a bit confusing that the sort order is swapped without me asking for it.

If I am sorting on popularity it should also sort on popularity.

For an added bonus, when the user filter box is cleared, the paging numbers should re-appear as well.

Comment: Am not seeing it, what's the irony?

Comment: But you created that other page at the same time, copy-pasting. How is it an ironic dupe when you deliberately cross-post?

Comment: Okay, but what's the funny part? Is it that you're having the same thing on another site and posted them at the same time when you realised it was happening here as well? Where is JokeExplainer when you need them?

Comment: So you're saying this is more of a waffle type situation than a funny one?

Comment: The same problem exists on the tags page too.

Comment: The Tags page had this too, was fixed, but now both Tags and Users always sort alphabetically.

Answer (score 2):

Just deployed this, its been bothering me for ages.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working: http://stackoverflow.com/users

Comment: Not only the sort order is broken, but some matches aren't showing. For example, if you type NullU it will only show one user (me). There is actually a user whose nick is [NullUser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/383255/nulluser)

Comment: @null exact matches are always pushed to the front what's the user id of this user

Comment: @waffles, compare newest and oldest with a filter of `Jo` here on MSO.

Comment: @waffles This: http://stackoverflow.com/users/383255/nulluser Also I should be the first non-exact match for "Null" when sorting by rep.

Comment: waffles, is SEDE getting updated any time soon?